# Notification When user add item into database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

i have a program that allow user to add data into database,but i want it look proper to admin to view the new item. Right now when user submit new data the admin can view all the data have been submitted from database but now i want the admin can alert the new data have been submitted by user. By the way i using asp.net,back end Vb.net and db is MYSQL.

Comment: @samitha right now i just looking for the easy method. but i try some Query Notifications. but it seem in SQL. i dont understand the explanation. That why i asking

Answer (score 1):

There are huge variety of ways how you could implement desired feature. General algorithm is next

1. Commit each user data sumbission event into storage
2. Gather all events by timer
3. Render gathered facts in admin UI

To achieve this consider to use for step 1 [MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Create additional table and save user data submission events into it.

Use scheduled asynchronous event monitoring for step 2,

Comment: i really don't understand..sorry seem i want to understand it but i don't get it. now i just a simple way. like when user submit data. in the admin page automatically the label will display you have 1 New submitted data.

Comment: More simple: 1. Create on insert trigger and save on insert event to new table(new_entries). 2. Periodically grab data from that table